# Encrypted swap not working after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, encryption, swap

`free` command tells there is zero swap.

/etc/fstab has line

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap noauto,sw 0 0
```

`cat /etc/crypttab` tells (in one line)

> cryptswap1 UUID=27a623c7-9621-4649-8a20-d2a3e5b48e5b /dev/urandom swap,offset=6,noauto,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256

`ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep -F 27a623c7-9621-4649-8a20-d2a3e5b48e5b` tells

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 kesä   9 05:41
>   27a623c7-9621-4649-8a20-d2a3e5b48e5b -> ../../sda6

`cat /proc/swaps` tells just

> Filename              Type        Size    Used    Priority

What is wrong? How to enable swap again?

Comment: Also, you might want to remove the `noauto` from the line as that prevents the swap from mounting at startup.

Comment: @Terrance I removed `noauto` from the line in /etc/fstab and then ran `sudo swapon -a` which resulted "swapon: stat of /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 failed: No such file or directory".

Comment: @Terrance I get exactly the same message, when running `sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap` according to your link.

Comment: @Terrance besides there is no file /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume so something has changed since 12.04.

Comment: @Terrance `swapon -s`is working at least now that I setup unencrypted swap.

Comment: I was actually able to set up a swap for me that is encrypted following this one:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308824/111521  You do need to run the `update-initramfs -u` and you need to reboot when that is complete.  Then it worked fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78830/discussion-between-jarno-and-terrance).

Comment: @Terrance Ok, I succeeded to setup encrypted swap, even using UUID in /etc/crypttab. No /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume file needed, and I think `update-initramfs -u` not needed either.

Comment: This is my /etc/crypttab: 'cryptswap1 UUID=6ceb7ab8-8752-45a1-b0e4-60529e38b9b4 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256'

Comment: Feel free to write up what you did as your own answer.  I will upvote it.  =)

Comment: @Terrance I'll try when I have time. I wonder why noauto" was added in the files? Maybe it was by the upgrade "process.

Comment: It could be....  I am not sure.  The other link I put up they were saying something about a bug, but to me it doesn't sound like yours is experiencing the bug.